# How to get lattitude longitude points of users current location when app is inactive or closed in react native android?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, location, expo

Thanks In advance..!

I am developing a app using react native expo, this application needs to track user current location when app is foreground or background or killed.

in any state i need to track the user current location.

I have tried some code and followed some plugins but no use.

Can any one help me, how to track the location in background using react native?

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade to Expo SDK v32.0.0** to use this feature

You can now use simple javascript lines to get updates on location in the background, and also trigger geofencing task when device leave or enter a location.

[Upgrading](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52) your SDK - for further steps

Upgrading Your App-
Close your Expo CLI server

In app.json, change sdkVersion to "32.0.0"

In package.json, change these dependencies:

- react-native to
  "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
- expo to "^32.0.0"
- react to "16.5.0" — (this exact version)
- react-navigation to "^3.0.9" (if you use it — this is also optional, 
     you don’t have to update it to use the newest SDK. If you choose to, 
     make sure you read the changelog for breaking changes, and see this 
     upgrade guide for upgrading from v2 to v3.)
- jest-expo to "^32.0.0" (if you use it)
- sentry-expo to "~1.9.0" (if you use it)

Delete your project’s node_modules directory and run npm install again (or use Yarn, we love Yarn)

Run expo start -c

Update the Expo app on your phones from the App Store / Google Play. expo-cli will automatically update your apps in simulators.

Make sure to check the breaking changes section of this post!

If you built a standalone app previously, remember that you will need to create a new build in order to update the SDK version. 
Run expo build:ios or expo build:android when you are ready to do a new build for submission to stores.

**If you are planning to submit your iOS app to the App Store, you must upgrade to Xcode 10 in order to do so.**

Comment: It is good to add url as part of reference but add relevant details which will be helpful to resolve to issue, url might get invalidated in future so will this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think we all agree that this is a "highly requested feature". The problem is W3C, IETF, and in particular Jake Archibald refuse to acknowledge it :-(

If they just spec'd the TravelManager (analogous to PushManager for background notifications) as it is DETAILED [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) you could have Background Geolocations without ANY plugins!

No Cordova, No Expo, No PhoneGap, and No Native App requirement.

Can anyone explain why W3C and IETF simply refuse?